# insert text in input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, getelementbyid

I am using some JavaScript within an angular project (I am not familiar with angular.js, hence Js). I have a text input field in my form with a placeholder by default. I want to insert some actual text into the field depending on user action.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="logon" name="logon" ng-model="user.logon" placeholder= "Username" required>
```

When I run

```
var x = document.getElementById("logon");
x.value = "a";
```

nothing happens. Yet, when I use

```
var x = document.getElementById("logon");
x.placeholder = "b";
```

the place-holder text is changed, This would surely indicate that the code is running at the correct time, just that I'm missing something in the `x.value` code line?

Comment: If your using AngularJS, you should change the model of the input… http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: try this x.value('a'); @myol

Comment: @NomiAli `value` is not a function.

Comment: val('a'); sort of this.

Comment: Not sort of, that IS a function, but that is jQuery.

Comment: myol, it should work. I think you are again overriding the value in preceding code. can you please post the related code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is looking like angularJS . SO you can do it by ng-model

```
$scope.user.logon = "a";
```

Comment: Thankyou! This is what is was. Thanks for helping me with my clear lack of knowledge of angularjs.